# React - get value of selected element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a set of countries, and each country has a set of cities.

I want to print a dropdown where the user selects a country, and then for that selected country I want to display all cities in another dropdown.

However, how can I know which country was selected?

```
 handleSelect: function(indexOfSelectedCountry){

    },

    render: function(){

        var countryNames = this.props.countries.map(function(elem){
            return <option><a href="#">{elem.name}</a></option>
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <p>Select category</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="form-control" onselect={this.handleSelect(What do I put here?)}>
                        {countryNames}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I want to do something like the above, but I don't know how to pass the result of the selection to a listening method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put anything in your parenthesis, this is how you retrieve the selected value (notice the onChange and event usage)

```
handleSelect: function(event) {
   var optionValue = event.target.value
   ...
},
render: function(){

    var countryNames = this.props.countries.map(function(elem){
        return <option><a href="#">{elem.name}</a></option>
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <p>Select category</p>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelect}>
                    {countryNames}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Can I get the index of the element rather than its value? I have simplified the code in my question; instead of names, I am actually selecting from descriptions, which are not unique. Therefore, I would like to get something unique from the selection, such as the index.

Comment: You could use the index as the option value in your map function: `var countryNames = this.props.countries.map(function(elem, index){
        return <option value={index}><a href="#">{elem.name}</a></option>
    });`

Comment: you should specify a key as well... react will raise a warning if you dont.. `var countryNames = this.props.countries.map(function(elem, index){ return <option value={index} key={index}><a href="#">{elem.name}</a></option> });`

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
<select class="form-control" onChange={ e => this.handleSelect(e.target.value)}>
  {countryNames}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
handleSelect: function(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
},

render: function(){

    var countryNames = this.props.countries.map(function(elem){
        return <option><a href="#">{elem.name}</a></option>
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <p>Select category</p>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select class="form-control" onselect={this.handleSelect}>
                    {countryNames}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```